# Android Facebook Log In with AWS Cognito

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm having trouble authenticating users with Facebook and creating a single new identity with AWS Cognito. Then if that user deletes the app and re-downloads it I want Cognito to return the same identity.

Facebook login works but credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins); creates 4 NEW unauthenticated identities every time.

```
    final CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(getApplicationContext(), "xxxxxxxx", Regions.US_EAST_1);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_friends"));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            updateWithToken(currentAccessToken);

        }
    };

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
            logins.put("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
            Log.d("LogTag", "my ID is " + logins);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problem connecting to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });

}

private void updateWithToken(AccessToken token) {
    if (token != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LogIn.this, NavDrawer.class);
        LogIn.this.startActivity(intent);

    }
    ;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    updateWithToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Intent intent = new Intent(LogIn.this, Buffer.class);
    LogIn.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Any help would be amazing, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are starting a new activity every time your access token from Facebook is updated. That mean you are creating different instances of CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider every time, which is not right.

Ideally you should have CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider as a singleton in your application and use is in all you activities and app logic. You can use the [Cognito sample application](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) as an example to model the flow.